# Python Tic-Tac-Toe cant print out Tie and Computer bot still moves after player wins

Tags: python

I recently started studying python and I started my first project which is the tic-tac-toe. However, my problem is that whenever the player won the game, the computer bot will still input a move on the board. The second problem I have is whenever there is a tie, it doesn't print the tie.
Here is the code:

```py
import random

print("Welcome to tic-tac-toe. You will be battling with a dumb AI")


class TicTacToe:
    # create the board
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = []
        self.player = ""

    def player_choice(self):
        while True:
            choice = input("\nPlease Select if you want O or X \n1. O\n2. X\nEnter your choice: ")
            if choice == "1":
                print("You picked \"O\"  ")
                self.player = "O"
                break
            elif choice == "2":
                print("You picked \"X\"  ")
                self.player = "X"
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid Input")

    def create_board(self):
        for i in range(3):
            self.board.append(["-"] * 3)

    def print_board(self):
        for row in self.board:
            print("|".join(row))

    # Check winner
    def check_winner(self):
        # check row
        for row in self.board:
            if row[0] == row[1] == row[2] and row[0] != "-":
                return row[0]
        # check column
        for col in range(3):
            if self.board[0][col] == self.board[1][col] == self.board[2][col] and self.board[0][col] != "-":
                return self.board[0][col]
        # check diagonal
        if self.board[0][0] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[2][2] and self.board[0][0] != "-":
            return self.board[0][0]
        if self.board[0][2] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[2][0] and self.board[0][2] != "-":
            return self.board[0][2]
        # check for tie
        if "-" not in self.board[0] and "-" not in self.board[1] and "-" not in self.board[2]:
            print("It's a tie!")
        # no winner no tie
        return None

    def get_move(self):
        print("You are using " + self.player)
        if self.player == "X":
            while True:
                row = int(input("Input Row: "))
                col = int(input("Input Column: "))
                if row < 0 or row >= len(self.board) or col < 0 or col >= len(self.board[0]):
                    print("out of Bounds")
                elif self.board[row][col] == "-":
                    self.board[row][col] = self.player
                    break
                else:
                    print("Someone is already in that spot!")

            print("Player O (computer) is making a move...")
            row, col = random.randint(0, 2), random.randint(0, 2)
            while self.board[row][col] != "-":
                row, col = random.randint(0, 2), random.randint(0, 2)
            print(f"Player O chooses ({row + 1},{col + 1})")
            self.board[row][col] = "O"

        elif self.player == "O":
            while True:
                row = int(input("Input Row: "))
                col = int(input("Input Column: "))
                if row < 0 or row >= len(self.board) or col < 0 or col >= len(self.board[0]):
                    print("out of Bounds")
                elif self.board[row][col] == "-":
                    self.board[row][col] = self.player
                    break
                else:
                    print("Someone is already in that spot!")

            print("Player X (computer) is making a move...")
            row, col = random.randint(0, 2), random.randint(0, 2)
            while self.board[row][col] != "-":
                row, col = random.randint(0, 2), random.randint(0, 2)
            print(f"Player X chooses ({row + 1},{col + 1})")
            self.board[row][col] = "X"

    def play_game(self):
        self.player_choice()
        self.create_board()
        while True:
            self.print_board()
            self.get_move()
            winner = self.check_winner()
            if winner:
                self.print_board()
                print(f"Player {winner} wins!")
                break



game = TicTacToe()
game.play_game()
```

Comment: Yes because you tell the computer to always make a move after the player. Also the player always begins thus when the last move (9th) is always made by the player. Now the computer is looking for an empty square, but does not find one in other words is stuck in the while True loop.

Answer (score 0):

The computer bot makes a move in `get_move()` method. You check if there is a winner after this method is done in `check_winner()` method. Therefore the computer bot will always make a move after user makes a move. To resolve this issue I suggest you to split `get_move()` into two methods: `get_player_move()` and `get_bot_move()`. Then you can check if player win after player makes a move.

```
self.get_player_move()
winner = self.check_winner()
# if player wins, bot will not make a move
if not winner:
    self.get_bot_move()
    winner = self.check_winner()
```

When the game ends with a tie, your method `check_winner()` prints out the message and returns `None` and your `while True` cycle continues.

```
if "-" not in self.board[0] and "-" not in self.board[1] and "-" not in self.board[2]:
    # print("It's a tie!")
    return 'tie'
```

If you combine both of these solutions, the main loop will look like this

```
result = None
while not result:
    self.print_board()
    self.get_player_move()
    result = self.check_winner()
    # if player wins, bot will not make a move
    if not result:
        self.get_bot_move()
        result = self.check_winner()

if result == 'tie':
    print("It's a tie!")
else:
    print(f"Player {result} wins!")
```